# While loop not handling the exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, exception, user-input

Here is the list from the selection of cities:

```
city_choice = ["chicago","new york city","washington"]
```

Within the while loop below I am trying to have the user input a city from the list with an exception handler to let user know that isn't a choice and to select from the list. Why is the while loop not processing that?

```
while True:
try:
    city = input("Please enter city: ")
except ValueError:
    if city != [0,2]:
        print("Sorry, that isn\'t a choice.")
        #try again
        continue
    else:
        #city was successfully selected
        #Exit the loop.
        break
```

Comment: `input()` accepts anything.  I don't think it can ever raise `ValueError`.

Comment: I realized that when I posted, I added an if statement within the except to let it know if one the choices were not selected. Still didn't work for me.

Comment: Update your question to contain the latest code you're actually using.

Comment: Try-except-structures are for catching errors which let your program exit because it cannot handle sth anymore (div 0 or sth similar). What you are trying to catch is a semantic error, ie an error with respect what _you_ as the author of the program initially wanted to have, but now (eg because of user input) came different than it _should in your mind_. For this, you need if ... elif ... else.

Answer (score 1):

No need for try/except.  Just use the `in` operator:

```
city_choice = ["chicago","new york city","washington"]

while True:
    city = input("Please enter city: ")
    if city in city_choice:
        break
    print("Sorry, that isn\'t a choice.")
```

Comment: I think I was over complicating here. Thanks for the input. I believe my confusion stems from the fact that the section I was reading recently had exception handling.